# Attempt do de-reference null object

Tags: apex, controller

I'm in a little bit of struggle here. Have an error in this class. I tried to debug log this error but I don't understand why only one user is having this problem. For the rest of the users this error does not occur. This is the error:

> Visualforce Page: /apex/VisitReportPage
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
> Class.VisitReportPageExtension.setIsFullReport: line 105, column 1
> Class.VisitReportPageExtension.: line 65, column 1

This is my class:

```
public with sharing class VisitReportPageExtension {

    public List<SelectOption> PicklistValues { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> SecondPicklistValues { get; set; }
    public List<SelectOption> LastPicklistValues { get; set; }
    public Map<String, String> PicklistMap = new Map<String, String>();

    Public List<String> selectedValues { get; set; }
    Public List<String> SecondselectedValues { get; set; }
    public List<String> LastSelectedValues { get; set; }

    public static final String DEFAULT_TASK_STATUS = 'New';
    public static final String DEFAULT_TASK_PRIORITY = 'Normal';

    public static final String EVENT_URL_PARAM = 'EventID';
    public static final String RETURN_URL_PARAM = 'retUrl';
    public static final String RECORD_TYPE_URL_PARAM = 'RecordType';
    public static final String ACCOUNT_URL_PARAM = 'AccountId';
    public static final String OPPORTUNITY_URL_PARAM = 'OpportunityId';

    public static final String MEMO_REPORT_DEVELEOPER_NAME = 'Call_Memo';

    private List<List<String>> contactFields;
    private Map<ID, Contact> contactsCache = new Map<ID, Contact>();
    private Map<ID, User> userCache = new Map<ID, User>();
    private List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
    private Map<Id, RecordType> mInteractionReportRecordTypes = null;

    private boolean isFullReport = true;
    private String retURLParam = null;

    public Boolean isNew { get; private set; }
    public Boolean showCreateContactPopup { get; set; }

    public List<ActionItemWrapper> actionItems { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerParticipantWrapper> customerParticipants { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerParticipantWrapper> internalParticipants { get; set; }
    public Contact contactHandler { get; set; }

    public Visit_Report__c record { get; set; }

    /**
     * Constructor creates instance of class. Loads Interaction 
     * report and related records.
     * @param  stdCtr Standard controller.
    */
    public VisitReportPageExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtr) {
        customerParticipants = new List<CustomerParticipantWrapper>();
        internalParticipants = new List<CustomerParticipantWrapper>();

        record = (Visit_Report__c) stdCtr.getRecord();
        isNew = (stdCtr.getId() == null);

        mInteractionReportRecordTypes =
                RecordTypeService.getRecordTypesForObject('Visit_Report__c');
        loadParams();

        loadInteractionRecord();
        clearContactHandler();
        closeCreateContactPopup();
        setIsFullReport(record.RecordTypeId);


        selectedValues = new List<String>();
        SecondselectedValues = new List<String>();
        LastSelectedValues = new List<String>();

        PicklistValues = new List<SelectOption>();
        SecondPicklistValues = new List<SelectOption>();
        LastPicklistValues = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> FieldPicklistvalues =
                Visit_Report__c.Innovation_presented_to_customer__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry FieldPicklistvaluesfor : FieldPicklistvalues) {
            PicklistValues.add(new SelectOption(FieldPicklistvaluesfor.getValue(),
                    FieldPicklistvaluesfor.getLabel()));
            PicklistMap.put(FieldPicklistvaluesfor.getvalue(),
                    FieldPicklistvaluesfor.getLabel());
        }
    }


    private void loadParams() {
        Map<String, String> mGetParams = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        record.EventID__c = mGetParams.get(EVENT_URL_PARAM);
        retURLParam = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get(RETURN_URL_PARAM);

        //TODO get rec type 
        if (record.RecordTypeId == null) {
            if (mGetParams.containsKey(RECORD_TYPE_URL_PARAM)) {
                record.RecordTypeId = mGetParams.get(RECORD_TYPE_URL_PARAM);
            }
        }
        if (mGetParams.containsKey(ACCOUNT_URL_PARAM)) {
            record.Account_Name__c = mGetParams.get(ACCOUNT_URL_PARAM);
        }
    }

    private void setIsFullReport(Id recordTypeId) {
        isFullReport = (mInteractionReportRecordTypes.get(recordTypeId).DeveloperName != MEMO_REPORT_DEVELEOPER_NAME);
    }


    public boolean getIsFullReport() {
        return isFullReport;
    }
}
```

Why this error only occurs for only one user? I don't know why the code breaks. Any suggestions?

---

this is what I have from Debug Logs:

```
08:31:44.0 (38808886)|METHOD_ENTRY| 
[8]|01p58000007JayN|RecordTypeSelector.getRecordTypesForObject(String)
08:31:44.0 (38834531)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[18]|objectName|String|false|false
08:31:44.0 (38852498)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[18]|objectName|"Visit_Report__c"

08:31:44.0 (62503783)|METHOD_EXIT| 
[8]|01p58000007JayN|RecordTypeSelector.getRecordTypesForObject(String)
08:31:44.0 (62631377)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|recordTypes|"Map of size 8 too large to 
display"|0x1dfeeca5

Class.RecordTypeSelector.getRecordTypesForObject: line 20, column 1: [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType=:objectName]: executed 1 time in 23 ms
```

Hope it helps... I'm not a developer...

Comment: I suppose, that the user which gets this error does not have access to **Visit_Report__c** object. Therefore, mInteractionReportRecordTypes is null for this user and you get *NullPointerException*.

Comment: But it does... this user is using a profile 'SALES' and for other users which are using this profile is working perfectly...I also tested with this user with System Admin Profile and the error still occurs..

Comment: Hi Cristian, welcome to SFSE. Please, take a [tour], read [ask] and make your question's title a bit more specific. "Attempt do de-reference null object" is quite a common error and does not say anything about your particular problem.

Comment: What is the value of `recordTypeId` when this fails?